# Trim Titles Only On Some Pages

Tags: php, functions, text, get-the-title

I Need to Trim the `h2.entry-title`, including whitespace and special character Only On Homepage, Category Pages, and Tag Pages.

(eg. Gowland Remote Control Car **– RC Cars Xmas Gifts**)

I Need All Titles Like This

(Gowland Remote Control Car)

**I need to trim all the characters after “-”**

Please Help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: You said this needs to happen only on some pages, how do we know which pages to run this on? And what is the `- RC Cars Xmas Gifts`? Is it a subtitle?

Comment: Hi, This Needs to run on Frontpage, Category Pages, and Tag Pages. And  ```- RC Cars Xmas Gifts``` is the part I need to remove from the title. Need To Trim all the characters after “-”

Comment: And how are you displaying the title currently? I don't see any code outputting titles in your question, edit the question to include the code you are trying to modify

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim this things for title tag or for heading of any template or in any php file? because `- RC Cars Xmas Gifts` is looks like site title. please share your code which you are trying.